# Injecting in Net 6 - 'IManager<IStrategy<Options>>' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

With Net 6 and C# 10 I have:

```
public class Options { }

public interface IStrategy<out T> where T: Options {
  T Options { get; }
}

public abstract class Strategy<T> : IStrategy<T> where T : Options {
  public abstract T Options { get; }
}

public interface IManager<T> where T: IStrategy<Options> {
  T? Strategy { get; set; }
}

public class Manager<T> : IManager<T> where T : IStrategy<Options> {
  public T? Strategy { get; set; }
}
```

I need to inject `IManager` in a Net 6 application:

```
services.AddTransient<IManager<IStrategy<Options>>, Manager<IStrategy<Options>>();
```

But I get the error:

```
'IManager<IStrategy<Options>>' is a type, which is not valid in the given context
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Seems like a syntax issue?

Shouldn't be like services.AddTransient<IManager<IStrategy<Options>>, Manager<IStrategy<Options>>>();

Comment: *How to solve this?* - count the number of < and the number of > you have used